VBA Show Powerpoint Slides Based On Day - Office 365
Good morning,
We currently have powerpoint presentations that run with a daily schedule and pictures. Currently I've had to make a presentation for each day, which doesn't sound bad, until there are new pictures each month.  This means I have to change the pictures on 7 presentations, or create one presentation with the new pictures as a template and copy/paste the day schedule slides, pick "save as...", and over-write the previous months presentations for that specific day.  Considering I do this as a volunteer thing, it's time consuming sometimes without getting paid.
The presentations go like this:
Slide 1: Monday Schedule
Slide 2-6: Pictures
Slide 7: Monday Schedule
Slide 8-12: Pictures
Etc...
There can be around 30 pictures for each presentation.  And it plays on a loop for the day.
My question is, is there a way I can just have slides for Mon-Sun in one presentation, and it knows to pick that days slide if it is that day currently?  And instead of having that days schedule slide shown multiple times, just have it pick a random shuffle of 5 pictures, show the slide, random shuffle, show the slide.  One major annoyance of having the day schedule slide copied multiple times in one presentation is that if they tell me to make a change for the day, I have to change multiple slides instead of just one. Although normally I'll just change one, and copy/paste it where it goes and remove the incorrect slides.
I hope all of this makes sense and that I described it correctly.  I did VBA many many years ago, and I'm willing to write the code.  I just don't know where to begin, and I can't find anyone through google that has needed to create something like this.
I haven't begun yet as I don't know where to begin and what is the smartest way to go about it.

While this is surely possible with VBA, it sounds like quite some work. Starting with the fact that Powerpoint will not automatically run macros, but they must be started by hand. Maybe the first question is, why don't you save the schedule as image instead and use one of the many programs that show images in a folder as slideshow. There might even be one where you can set the order e.g. with a text file. Then you can swap out the schedule and/or other image files individually anytime.

What if you had a presentation for each day but link to the picture files instead of inserting them normally? You'd only have to change the original image file once; it'd be updated anywhere it's used as a link in any of the presentations.

I really like the idea of using links instead of pictures.  That would make life a whole lot easier with the process of updating.
I wouldn't be able to use the schedule as a picture because it has the date and time automatically updated.  They use it to tell the time.
Thank you for the ideas though.  The ability to quickly change the pictures from where they are pulled from helps alot more than dealing with a bunch of code!

Tell me what volunteering this is for -- i might help you with the code.
